# How to install windows 7 alongside ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, windows-8

I know this is a bit twisted but I have ubuntu 12.04 installed alongside Windows 8. But now my windows 8 has stopped working. I don't wanna fix it, I just wanna install Windows 7 without loosing ubuntu. Can it be done? How? I'm a newbie at this so please provide a detailed procedure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Insert your windows 7 DVD / USB and reboot..

Follow the installation normally , when it comes to the stage of which type of install , choose custom installation. Then you can choose the drive where you installed Windows 8,

There either format windows 8 drive or choose to save windows 8 files under windows.old folder!